# Using Google Analytics raw data to display graph by month

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, chart.js

**What I have done:**

I've used an API query and got `json` formatted data from Google Analytics via PHP. I've used `chartjs.org` to display chart. It's working fine as described in its doc.

**Here is the result from above:**
[image: graph from cartjs]

**GA admin:**

But in GA admin the result is grouped by month. This is because if time span increases, above chart's x axis labels will become congested. How can I achieve the graph below and group the data by month?

[image: goal graph]

**My js data:**

```
var salesChartData = {
    labels: ["2016 Jun, 11","2016 Jun, 12","2016 Jun, 13","2016 Jun, 14","2016 Jun, 15","2016 Jun, 16","2016 Jun, 17","2016 Jun, 18","2016 Jun, 19","2016 Jun, 20","2016 Jun, 21","2016 Jun, 22","2016 Jun, 23","2016 Jun, 24","2016 Jun, 25","2016 Jun, 26","2016 Jun, 27","2016 Jun, 28","2016 Jun, 29","2016 Jun, 30","2016 Jul, 01","2016 Jul, 02","2016 Jul, 03"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Electronics",
        fillColor: "rgba(5, 141, 199,.1)",
        strokeColor: "#058dc7",
        pointColor: "#058dc7",
        pointStrokeColor: "#058dc7",
        pointHighlightFill: "#0371a0",
        pointHighlightStroke: "#0371a0",
        data: ["18","4","39","25","19","23","19","11","7","21","14","19","24","29","6","8","29","29","15","18","13","3","4"],

      }
    ]
  };
```

What need to change in the above code to achieve a chart like GA?

Answer (score 0):

What I found , latest version of chart js has option to showxLable that will do this job but exactly not what is needed. Its just showing number of label not grouping the data.

`[demo]`[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trhcafut/)